# Will replacing spark plugs fix this?

Tags: exhaust, sparkplugs, emissions

My husband and I purchased a 2011 Mazda 6 2-3 months ago. It had 71,000 mi on it when purchased.

One accident, but only cosmetic.

A few weeks after driving it, I noticed some jerking when coming from a stop and when accelerating too quickly.

I wrote it off as having a heavy foot, but the problem persists. Not check engine light never came on until recently (of course) on our 17-hour drive to our home town.

We had a diagnostic test ran on the car and there’s a huge amount of lost connection codes which we think leads to a bad fuse, an emissions exhaust issue, which explains the revving, and also it needs new spark plugs.

So my question is, by replacing the spark plugs, will we be able to get back home without as much jerking and revving?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: get the repair done and you can drive the car,changing the spark plugs are unlikely to do any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Plugs are a cheap and easy fix, so do it anyway. If it still has issues, pay a garage to look at it - they'll probably find the source error code which is triggering all the others (we hope).

For better info, we'd need a list of all the codes found.

Comment: On the otherhand, it is exceptionally unlikely for modern platinum plugs to fail . I have changed out two sets of platinum plugs at over 100,000 miles .. I hated to throw them away because all 16 looked perfect. Computer controlled engines work great , until they don't. You probably need a Mazda dealer to fix it.

Comment: 2011 Mazda6 Service Schedule says change plugs at 75K for the 2.5L engine, 100K for the 3.7L. But the codes are the important question - they should reveal a lot.